# Python order a dict by key value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I've been trying to order my dict that has keys with this format: `"0:0:0:0:0:x"` where x is the variable that get incremented while filling the dict.

Since dictionaries doesn't insert in order, and I need the key-value values to be showed ordered, I tried to use

```
collections.OrderedDict(sorted(observation_values.items())
```

where observation_values is my dict, but values are ordered caring about the first number, like this:

```
"0:0:0:0:0:0": [0.0], "0:0:0:0:0:1": [0.0], "0:0:0:0:0:10": [279.5],
"0:0:0:0:0:100": [1137.8], "0:0:0:0:0:101": [1159.4], "0:0:0:0:0:102":
[1180.3], "0:0:0:0:0:103": [1193.6]...
```

till `"0:0:0:0:0:109"` then back to `"0:0:0:0:0:11"` and then again `"0:0:0:0:0:110"`, `..:111`, `..:112`.

How can I avoid using only most significant numbers to order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are sorting strings, so they are sorted lexicographically, not numerically.

Give `sorted()` a custom sort key:

```
sortkey = lambda i: [int(e) for e in i[0].split(':')]
collections.OrderedDict(sorted(observation_values.items(), key=sortkey))
```

This takes the key of each key-value pair (`i[0]`), splitting it on the `:` colon and converting each number in that key to an integer. Now the keys will be sorted lexicographically across the parts, and numerically per part; now `0:0:0:0:0:1` sorts before `0:0:0:0:0:100` and both sort before `0:0:0:0:1:0`.

Answer (score 0):

May be this help

```
>>>sorted(observation_values.items(),key=lambda x: int(x[0].split(":")[-1]))
```